# JAX RS Jersey + XML --> HTTP 400 Bad Request

Tags: xml, jaxb, jax-rs

@Sikorski 
/*This is my web.xml.*/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

 <display-name>Elite_Prepaid_New</display-name> 
  <servlet>
<display-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>com.elite_prepaid_new.users</param-name>
    <param-value>UsersResource</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>UserRoles.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list> 
</web-app>
```

/*This is the server log of tomcat. But it didn't show me any error messges.*/

```
This is the log file from tomcat. But it didn't show me there's any error. 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2013:11:04:12 -0700] "GET /     HTTP/1.1" 404 951
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jul/2013:11:04:12 -0700] "GET /Elite_Prepaid_New/ HTTP/1.1" 200 936
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jul/2013:11:11:56 -0700] "POST /Elite_Prepaid_New/services/transactions/add HTTP/1.1" 400 990
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jul/2013:13:56:10 -0700] "POST /Elite_Prepaid_New/services/transactions/add HTTP/1.1" 400 990
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jul/2013:13:56:36 -0700] "POST /Elite_Prepaid_New/services/transactions/add HTTP/1.1" 400 990
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jul/2013:14:06:36 -0700] "POST /Elite_Prepaid_New/services/transactions/add HTTP/1.1" 400 990
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jul/2013:14:07:11 -0700] "GET /Elite_Prepaid_New/ HTTP/1.1" 200 936
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jul/2013:14:07:14 -0700] "GET /Elite_Prepaid_New/ HTTP/1.1" 200 936
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jul/2013:14:07:14 -0700] "GET /Elite_Prepaid_New/ HTTP/1.1" 200 936
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jul/2013:14:07:14 -0700] "GET /Elite_Prepaid_New/ HTTP/1.1" 200 936
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jul/2013:14:07:59 -0700] "POST /Elite_Prepaid_New/services/transactions/add HTTP/1.1" 400 990
```

/*This is the updated question with the full stack trace from tomcat*/

```
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in     production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;C:\Users\Web Developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\;C:\Users\Web Developer\Desktop\eclipse;;.
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:04 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Elite_Prepaid_New' did not find a matching property.
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:04 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Restdemo' did not find a matching property.
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:04 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:04 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1275 ms
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:com:sun:jersey:api:view is already defined
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:com:sun:jersey:api:view is already defined
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:com:sun:jersey:api:view is already defined
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:08 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:08 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.myeclipseide.ws.CustomersResource
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:08 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Provider classes found:
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonParseExceptionMapper
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:08 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.14 09/09/2012 07:21 PM'
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:com:sun:jersey:api:view is already defined
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:com:sun:jersey:api:view is already defined
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:com:sun:jersey:api:view is already defined
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:10 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
/WEB-INF/lib

 /WEB-INF/classes
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:08 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.myeclipseide.ws.CustomersResource
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:08 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Provider classes found:
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonParseExceptionMapper
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:08 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.14 09/09/2012 07:21 PM'
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:com:sun:jersey:api:view is already defined
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:com:sun:jersey:api:view is already defined
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:com:sun:jersey:api:view is already defined
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:10 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:11 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.elite_prepaid_new.users.UsersResource
  class com.elite_prepaid_new.orders.OrdersResource
  class com.elite_prepaid_new.user_roles.UserRolesResource
  class com.elite_prepaid_new.items.ItemsResource
  class com.elite_prepaid_new.live.AddingTransResource
  class com.elite_prepaid_new.items.types.ItemsTypesResource
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:11 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Provider classes found:
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonParseExceptionMapper
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:11 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.14 09/09/2012 07:21 PM'
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 15, 2013 11:04:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7094 ms
```

I have one issue in sending the request xml from RestClient to Jax Rs.
I accepted and saved this request with the bean which is a jaxb object.
But, whenever I made a request, server returns HTTP 400 bad request.

Here is my XML request.

```
<trans>
  <rechargephone>0990909</rechargephone>
  <phonetype>GSM</phonetype>
  <amount>10000</amount>
  <useracctid>10100100</useracctid>
  <userpin>111</userpin>
  <quantity>1</quantity>
</trans>
```

And here is my resource method

```
public class AddingTransResource {

@POST
@Path("add")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public Message add(Trans trans) {

    Trans transaction = new Trans();
```

The method `add` is accepting the XML parameter with the JAXB object, in here, which is `Trans` and it is also the root element of this XML.

Below is my JAXB object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Trans {

private String rechargephone;
private String phonetype;
private String amount;
private String useracctid;
private String userpin;
private int quantity;

public String getRechargephone() {
    return rechargephone;
}
public void setRechargephone(String rechargephone) {
    this.rechargephone = rechargephone;
}
```

And the way that i'm creating the JAXB object is just creating a Java bean with `@XmlRootElement`.

Can anyone suggest me please how to fix it and any idea on creating the JAXB object?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you pleas add the exct `Exception` including the stack trace from the erver side?

Comment: Tks for you reply, Plonus.

Comment: @Uwe Plonus. The exact Exception is HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request. Description is the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. And the server I'm using is Apache Tomcat/7.0.41.

Comment: Please add the client code you use to create the request. And please also check that the provider to convert XML to  `Trans` is correctly registerd on the server side.

Comment: i didn't use the client code. instead, i use the RESTClient with POST method... and the url is http://localhost:8080/Elite_Prepaid_New/services/addingtrans/addtransaction, and with the xml request body.. and for the provider, i just use the javabean with @XmlRootElement...

Comment: See if you can turn on logging of the actual messages (or add in some kind of interceptor) so you can check that the request is _actually_ correct, instead of just assuming that it is.

Comment: Two things, first please post your web.xml or any other config file and are you validating this request ?

Comment: I compared your web.xml with http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/#first_servletdispatcher, your param name and value in init section looks different. I am not sure if that has something to do with 400 but still !

Answer (score 2):

You might need an XML namespace declaration (xmlns) to your root element declaration.

Otherwise, activate verbose tracing on Jersey with the following parameter in the web.xml :

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.TracePerRequest</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>      
</init-param>
```

Afterwards, send your HTTP request with the following header :

```
X-Jersey-Trace-Accept=true
```

Comment: Worth mentioning detailed description of this feature - https://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/tracing_in_jersey

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some detail wrong with your XML request... the JAXB and API seem to be well defined. I would suggest you try two things:

1) add an header to the XML request, which would lead to the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<trans>
<rechargephone>0990909</rechargephone>
<phonetype>GSM</phonetype>
<amount>10000</amount>
<useracctid>10100100</useracctid>
<userpin>111</userpin>
<quantity>1</quantity>
</trans>
```

2) add specifically a name of the JAXB object in the XmlRootElement:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="trans")
```

Hope it helps. If not, provide further logging info of the exception raised (not only the HTTP Status 400 - you can get that info from the Tomcat console and log files).

Comment: tks for your help.. but problem is still happening.. I will check the exception stack trace as per your suggestion.

Comment: can you try to update your XML header to <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> (the "standalone" was missing in my answer... this tells that this has no dependency on other XML files).

Comment: standalone also cannot help.. :(

Comment: I suggest you update the question with the full trace of the exception so we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

As per other suggestions add the xml header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Also try adding the xmlns declaration to your root element, should be something similar to your package:

```
<trans xmlns="http://www.xsd.your/Package">
...
</trans>
```